# Creating a Java Regex with *

Tags: java, regex

I have to check format of filenames using regex.
There are filenames that will contain the format:

```
*_*_*.key
```

The problem is any string will match *, so a filename with a format `*_*_*_*_*_*_*.key` will also match the regex mentioned above.

I was thinking of counting the number of underscores(_) instead, but is there a way to check using a Regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by `any string will match *`? In regex a `*` is not a wildcard. Can you give some example strings that should match and should not match?

Answer (score 2):

use this regex `^([^_]_)+[^_]\.key$`
insted `+` you can write number of dashes f.e.`{2}`
regex will be `^([^_]_){2}[^_]\.key$`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match anything except underscore:

```
^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+\.key$
```

Use  `*` instead of `+` only if you want to allow zero characters.

```
^[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*\.key$
```